# dynamically change page content based on users location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, geolocation, blogs

I am new here. I am trying to build a web app with node.js, Express and MongoDB. Can anyone help me, I want to create a locationbased web app to render information based on the location? How can i do this?
With Geolocation I get my Users location data, but i dont know how to use this information to change the content of my webpage. It is a blog webapplication.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some ' if ' statements could work. Check if user is in that location and send him that content.